# Fire observable subscribe function first when user presses enter key using custombinding

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following input field in my html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: InputValue, returnAction: $root.columnFilter">
```

I have the following view model:

```
var viewmodel={
    InputValue:ko.observable(),
    getDataFromDb: function () {
       //code to get data from database
    },
    columnFilter: function () {
        viewmodel.getDataFromDb();
    }
}

$(function () {

    var beforeChangeHandler = function (value) {
        //do something
    }

    var afterChangeHandler = function (value) {
       //do something
    }

    viewmodel.InputValue.subscribe(beforeChangeGeneralFilterHandler, null, "beforeChange");
    viewmodel.InputValue.subscribe(afterChangeGeneralFilterHandler, null, "change");

    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
    viewmodel.getDataFromDb();

});
```

and I am using the following knockout custom binding for enter key press:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.returnAction = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                value(viewModel);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In the above case whenever user enters a value into the input field and presses the `enter` key, I have to call the `columnFilter` function. The problem I am facing is whenever the user enters a value and presses the enter key, the `columnFilter` method is called first and then the code written in the `beforeChangeHandler` and `afterChangeHandler` knockout `subscribe` functions are executed second which is messing up my logic.

What I want is that whenever user enters a value in the input field and presses the enter key, I want the `beforeChangeHandler` and `afterChangeHandler` knockout `subscribe` functions to execute first and then the `columnFilter` function.

What change should I make to my `enter` key custom binding to achieve this? Is there any other way to implement the `enter` key functionality for input fields in knockout while updating the `observables` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the change like this so the before and after change events will fire first:

```
$(element).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        ko.utils.triggerEvent(element, "change");
        value(viewModel);
    }
});
```